# unable to parse bindings knockout js for drop down list

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a drop down list in a form whose values need to be passed to a grid upon clicking save button. I am using kendo ui and knockout js

I am binding it in view model as :

JS

```
    this.blahList = ko.observableArray(["1", "1", "p3","c3ai"]);
    this.blah = ko.observable();

this is my add function:

    this.addBorrower = function() {
                        this.borrowers.push(new Borrower({ name: this.newName(), address: this.newAddress() , blah: this.newBlah()}));

                        };
```

HTML

```
<li>
blah :
<input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: blahList, value: newBlah}" />
</li>
```

it shows an error

ERROR

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: newBlah is not defined;
Bindings value: kendoDropDownList: { data: blahList, value: newBlah} 

Uncaught TypeError: Object #<AppViewModel> has no method 'newBlah'
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Is newBlah() related to this.blah?

Comment: blah=this.newBlah(). i am not sure about the syntax. but it is working for the text inputs.. doesnt work for drop down list

Comment: you do not declare newBlah anywhere in above code

Comment: i didnt define newName also. But that is working.. can you tell me the proper syntax @Anders

Comment: newName must be declared on the 'this' object somewhere otherwise you would get same result

Comment: yes i did.. but i changed it accordingly but the grid isnt populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kendoDropDownList binding is attempting to write the value from the dropdown to a property named "newBlah" which should be on your view model, but is not.

Change your view model to

```
this.blahList = ko.observableArray(["1", "1", "p3","c3ai"]);
this.newBlah = ko.observable(); //this is where the value will be stored
```

In other words, for the kendoDropDownList binding, the properties you assign to "data" and "value" must exist on your view model.  In this case, "blahList" and "newBlah" must exist on your view model.

Comment: thanks. the dropdown is working but the value isnt getting populated in the grid.

Comment: Yes, that's what I just explained.  The value from your dropdown is not being set anywhere when it changes, because you need to change this.blah to this.newBlah.